# Timthumb image thumbnails not appearing on wordpress site

Tags: image, wordpress, loading, woocommerce, timthumb

I'm trying to put together a page at http://www.sketch360.com/store/home/ which should show featured products and thumbnails for those products. For some reason the images aren't showing on page load, even though they immediately appear when you either right-click on the image, click on a next/previous arrow, or open 'developer tools' in chrome.

The status of the image styling in css I've noticed, changes from display:none to display:inline-block when you perform any of the above actions to get the images to show.

I've been through the timthumb troubleshooting steps at http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/11/timthumb-hints-tips/ and have changed permissions on all directories according to these instructions. Any help would be much appreciated in getting these images to show up on page load.

The images show up (also using the timthumb method, I believe) on this alternative page: http://www.sketch360.com/store/shop/  but not on the first page (that is going to form the home page for the site: http://www.sketch360.com/store/home/ ).

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a timthumb or wordpress issue.  It looks like it is a stylesheet / jQuery issue - where the div that covers the image (used for the highlight on hover) is opaque and covering the images.  The funny thing is that when I "Inspect Element", the images all appear.

Double-check your starting styles for class "overdefult" - make sure it has the right opacity or set the background color to transparent.  (You could also try removing it temporarily to prove that this div is indeed your issue.)

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for your comments - I've looked into this as far as I'm able to; I can also see the images when I 'Inspect Element'. All of the styles for "overdefult" appear to be correct; I've removed the overlay div that covers the image on hover, and the problem is still occuring. If you have any further ideas I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

After many hours banging my head against a brick wall, I have discovered an updated script available that controls the bxSlider used to display these images in li's - and having upgraded the minified script, the problem seems to have resolved itself - just in case there are others needing help on this too.